# Why did my installation of the upstream version of TexLive 2021 fail on Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, texlive-2021

I downloaded [the archive](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz), unpacked it, changed to the parrent directory and executed:
`./install-tl`. I chose the option D, specified the directory `/home/jerzy/texlive` and proceeded with the installation.
Towards the end of the installation I got the following output:

```
Installing [4248/4248, time/total: 02:04:06/02:23:29]: zztex [147k]
Retrying to install: arphic-ttf [12380k]
Retrying to install: asymptote-manual-zh-cn [878k]
Retrying to install: bibtexu.x86_64-linux [5533k]
Retrying to install: cbfonts [64879k]
Retrying to install: charissil [1306k]
Retrying to install: comprehensive [29211k]
Retrying to install: cstex [3871k]
Retrying to install: dnaseq [209k]
Retrying to install: einfart [553k]
Retrying to install: emf [320k]
Retrying to install: ethiop-t1 [5071k]
Retrying to install: fandol [21089k]
Retrying to install: featpost [17579k]
Retrying to install: fonts-tlwg [12364k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for /tmp/qhxNvn9TmC/amCBC97TSi/fonts-tlwg.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=b939062b365e252f7e3a21cbec2841fae7ed100ecbc800bef27a82491f920ab97ca4267f170047250c0afb2042a25bd38a21f128c47056baee91b69cc2e2d388, arg=7239ecb9ffb0dea42d339b1f758c3c4c11f18b6850b5265296c04027922d5ec882d7ee2b6eaf4abb0d2e702ff349833adedc36dd18eac492e191f43da267fdc9
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2399: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1978: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1813: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1729: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1633: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> ./install-tl:2135: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> ./install-tl:946: main::do_install_packages
 -> ./install-tl:700: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing /tmp/qhxNvn9TmC/amCBC97TSi/fonts-tlwg.tar.xz, but saving copy in /tmp/9_P5A9pp2R
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/fonts-tlwg.tar.xz
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
./install-tl: Writing log in current directory: /home/jerzy/install-tl-20210831/install-tl.log
```

I tried again and got a similar output, but this time checksums differed for `knuth-pdf` :

```
Installing [4248/4248, time/total: 01:57:16/02:07:08]: zztex [147k]
Retrying to install: aesupp [4394k]
Retrying to install: arabxetex [511k]
Retrying to install: arphic [26908k]
Retrying to install: bgteubner [2527k]
Retrying to install: braids [676k]
Retrying to install: cabin [2877k]
Retrying to install: ccool [812k]
Retrying to install: context [101788k]
Retrying to install: filemod [275k]
Retrying to install: fourier [557k]
Retrying to install: geschichtsfrkl [657k]
Retrying to install: glossaries-portuges [166k]
Retrying to install: gost [1811k]
Retrying to install: iodhbwm [3041k]
Retrying to install: knuth-pdf [44416k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for /tmp/4v3Rm1wO6E/prdZGCoH4W/knuth-pdf.doc.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=f30e79aabb76db7ed9ef8e130408bf140627d71d0d6fcee2b60043e6129fbc4b76a1cf83785bc414d6f6a30d79b8b3d1a784681e94ce4a9f204a315e8e5e5c42, arg=b6bb93794b064466c8bf7f79425a55a111a276a9888b720b7780756b5dbab86c6a573dedcd3946e4f7aa661b6bc6eecbc5f92068a50c0f17a3676e4077acfe0b
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2399: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1978: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1849: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1729: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1633: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> ./install-tl:2135: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> ./install-tl:946: main::do_install_packages
 -> ./install-tl:700: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing /tmp/4v3Rm1wO6E/prdZGCoH4W/knuth-pdf.doc.tar.xz, but saving copy in /tmp/iTbWkWrE1P
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/knuth-pdf.doc.tar.xz
Installation failed.
```

My environment: x86_64, Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.
What can I do in order to succeed with the installation?

Comment: which mirror did you use ? it seems that you may have a bad one you can specify a different mirror to use by specifying the repository URL

Comment: @David I have not specified the mirror, probaly one of the two Spanish mirrors was selected by default as I live in Spain. But Going to https://ctan.org/mirrors and selecting the mirror in France, 
`./install-tl --location https://ctan.gutenberg.eu.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/` , has not helped. I got :`Retrying to install: aboensis [34288k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for /tmp/jLIulf8Ui4/vLvWGSLNDv/aboensis.doc.tar.xz:`

Comment: That is something very different that installing from source. You are just installing the socalled upstream TeXLive (I use the same), where the installer comes as a Perl script and modules used by it.

Comment: @daleif True. I've already modified my question in response to your comment. Might downloading/mirroring the TeX Live repository be the solution to the issue in question?

Comment: Sometimes it might. The mirror I normally use seems to be decent enough and does not fail much. But I also have the option to rsync the tlnet folder from a mirror with rsync support directly to my harddrive and install from that. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html

Comment: Using the rsync is rather useful if you are in an area with slow internet. Let it sync over night. Then subsequent syncs will only grab the changes to the tlnet you are sync'ing from. Thus saving a lot of bandwidth